# Как получить динамический IP-адрес хоста для Ansible

Tags: linux, windows-10, ansible, manjaro

Хочу удаленно обновлять компьютеры с manjaro linux (arch) и windows 10.
Как получить IP-адрес хоста, для последующего управления им с помощью ansible, если он динамический и оба за оптическими роутерами?

Comment: 1: https://www.data-essential.com/ansible-how-to-collect-information-about-remote-hosts-with-gathers-facts/ 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819378/ansible-get-current-target-hosts-ip-address/  | It must helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Средствами ансибла вы не получите ip - т.к. он может его получить уже только после установления коннекта с машиной. Как вариант, ходите по dns - а дальше уже ансиблом определяйте ip.
Тогда будет выглядеть в таком виде:
инвентарь:

`[remote_servers]
name1.server
name2.server`

а в самой таске параметры ip вызываются как-то так:

`remote_ip_1: "{{hostvars[groups['remote_servers'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}"
remote_ip_2: "{{hostvars[groups['remote_servers'][1]]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']}}"`